# Google Maps: New markers are not showing after resuming map activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I am connecting my app to a sensor, everytime the sensor sends data a marker is placed on a map with data inside info window.

When I am starting the activity the first time. `mMap` has ID: 21319.
In my `onLocationChanged()`method I add markers to the map with ID 21319. Then if I press the back button and resume the activity. `mMap` is created again and has now another ID, let's say ID 22431. With my method `addMapPoints()` I add the old markers to `mMap` with ID 22431 with `mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)` and I can see the markers on the screen. But this time when new data is sent and markers are added inside `onLocationChanged()` no new markers appear on the screen. When I debug I can see that in `onLocationChanged()` my `mMap` has the old ID: 21319 and I do not get any errors. So I guess that the new markers are added to the old map but my screen is showing the new map.

Why is this happening? And how can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE** I think I have found the problem. At the moment `mMap == null` when new data is sent. What I now wonder is how can I obtain the map inside `OnLocationUpdate()` or in `OnResume()`?

Here is my MapsActivity code

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{

public GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
private int co_mV;
private int no2_mV;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private boolean initiateApp;
String currentTime;

TcpClient mTcpClient;
ArrayList<Marker> markerArrayList;
static  ArrayList<Double> markerLat = new ArrayList<>();
static  ArrayList<Double> markerLng = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<String> markerSnippet = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<String> markerTitle = new ArrayList<>();




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    initiateApp = true;
    markerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    markerArrayList.clear();
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();

        }
    }
    else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

    if (markerLat != null) {
        addMapPoints();
    }

    }


/* Here we create the infoWindow **/
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    getNewLocation();
    new ConnectTask().execute("");

}


public void newData(JSONObject d) {
    try {
        co_mV = d.getInt("co_mV");
        no2_mV = d.getInt("no2_mV");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    getNewLocation();
}

public void getTime() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());

}

public void getNewLocation() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

public void addMapPoints() {
    markerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < markerLat.size(); i++) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerLat.get(i), markerLng.get(i));
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(markerTitle.get(i));
        markerOptions.snippet(markerSnippet.get(i));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markerArrayList.add(marker);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (markerArrayList.size()>1) {
        if(location.distanceTo(mLastLocation) < 30) {
            markerArrayList.get(markerArrayList.size()-1).remove();
            markerArrayList.remove(markerArrayList.size()-1);
            markerSnippet.remove(markerSnippet.size()-1);
            markerTitle.remove(markerTitle.size()-1);
            markerLat.remove(markerTitle.size()-1);
            markerLng.remove(markerTitle.size()-1);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Reading to close to last reading, replaces last reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    if (markerArrayList.size() == 8) {
        markerArrayList.get(0).remove();
        markerArrayList.remove(0);
        markerSnippet.remove(0);
        markerTitle.remove(0);
        markerLat.remove(0);
        markerLng.remove(0);
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

if (co_mV != 0) {
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(latLng);
markerLat.add(location.getLatitude());
markerLng.add(location.getLongitude());
markerOptions.title("Time of reading: " + currentTime);
markerTitle.add("Time of reading: " + currentTime);
markerOptions.snippet("co: " + String.valueOf(co_mV) + " mV, " + "no2: " + String.valueOf(no2_mV) + " mV");
markerSnippet.add("co: " + String.valueOf(co_mV) + " mV, " + "no2: " + String.valueOf(no2_mV) + " mV");
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
markerArrayList.add(mCurrLocationMarker);
}



    mLastLocation = location;


    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));


    //move map camera

    if(initiateApp){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
    }

    boolean contains = mMap.getProjection()
            .getVisibleRegion()
            .latLngBounds
            .contains(latLng);

    if(!contains){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    initiateApp = false;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}

public JSONObject getNewJSON(JSONObject json) {
    try {

        int humidity = json.getInt("humidity_ppm");
        int pressure = json.getInt("pressure_Pa");
        int noise = json.getInt("noise_dB");
        double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

       JSONObject c = new JSONObject();
        c.put("time",time);
        c.put("lat",lat);
        c.put("long",lng);
        c.put("humidity",humidity);
        c.put("pressure",pressure);
        c.put("noise_dB",noise);
        return c;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's getting into the `if (co_mV != 0)` case?  Add logging to be sure

Comment: Yes, I am getting into the (co_mV != 0). Both snippet,title and position is added on the new marker. I am also not getting any error on mMap.addMarker(mCurrLocationMarker). The only thing I can see differs is that mMap has a different ID compared to the ID of mMap inside "addMapPoints()".

Comment: It seems like the only place that you call `addMapPoints()` is in the `onMapReady()` override.  Is that getting called when you resume?

Comment: Are you asking if i enter addMapPoints() method when resuming the activity? Cause if so, yes. addMapPoints is just for restoring the old markers. Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: I see now, I think that might be the problem. Since if I set mMap == null in onPause(). Then when resuming the activity and new data is sent then mMap == null. How would I make it so "onMapReady" is called in "onResume()"? Since it has a GoogleMap object as parameter. @DanielNugent

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by exiting the application in onDestroy method .
I think when fragment is reused marker cannot be placed in map

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    getActivity().finish();
    System.exit(0);
    super.onDestroy();


}
```